# Add extra column as a marker in laravel datatable

Tags: laravel, datatables, where-clause

What I want to do is to select the record from database based on two conditions, the first condition is to select all of the records that has reached 30 days today, and the second one is the records that has reached 25 days today based on the date field of the records. And for each condition I want to add a column (status) for marking the result. I want the result to be like this:

```
+--+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|No|        Date        |       Name        |       Status      |
+--+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1 |     2018-10-17     |       John        |       30 days     |
|2 |     2018-10-22     |      Daniel       |       25 days     |
+--+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

This is my query:

```
$data       = DB::table('data_pemohon')->select('*')->whereRaw('tanggal_permohonan + INTERVAL 30 DAY <= NOW()')->orWhereRaw('tanggal_permohonan + INTERVAL 25 DAY <= NOW()')->where('status_paspor','Serahkan paspor')->get();
return Datatables::of($data)->addIndexColumn()->make(true);
```

How can I do that, help me guys, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by 30 days interval? do you want data  matching exact date?

Comment: do you want exact match for `2018-10-22` date when it is 25 days interval?

Comment: No I want to check whether today the record is 30 or 25 days old @Sohel0415

Comment: and what happen for date `2018-10-20` and for date `2018-10-10`?

Comment: What do you mean? @Sohel0415

Comment: i mean what if you have records with that date? will you bring it with your query?

Comment: Only the record that has reached 30 or 25 days old today. @Sohel0415

Comment: exact 25 or 30 days? what happen if there is record which is 26 or 32 days form today?